# jquery function call strange behaviour

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to learn the basics of web site construction. Currently i'm working on a html file hosted on wamp, using jquery/xml/php files.
I have run into something very weird calling a simple function:

```
function showFreq(){
$('#freqD').html("Page refreshes every " + FREQ/1000 + " seconds.");}
```

Without calling this function, page loads properly (tab formatting, php, xml etc).
When i call this function inside **$(document).ready(function(){** the page shows up as if there are no scripts. However, if i replace the function call with the command inside it everything works as it is supposed to...

```
    $('#freqD').html("Page refreshes every " + FREQ/1000 + " seconds.");
///showFreq();
```

Needless to say that #freqD is a small div element at the bottom of the page containing nothing else in it. It annoys me too much to let it go.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: You need to show your code in context with where `var FREQ` is initialized and set.

Comment: Use jsfiddle to share your code. I've made a small example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/a79tj7fr/

Comment: Hey tyr, thanks for your time, this is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/a79tj7fr/2/

Comment: I'm new to this site, sorry for confusing you. As you see in the link above, if you use the function nothing appears, but if instead you 'comment' the function and un-comment the line above it works. Sorry for bad english, i hope you understand what i meant.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that you tried this ?

```
function showFreq(){
  $('#freqD').html("Page refreshes every " + FREQ/1000 + " seconds.");
}

$(function() {
  showFreq();
};
```